# linux C++ notify file type creation

Tags: c++, c, linux, inotify

I need to monitor the creation of a specific file type (with a known extension) in a specific folder in linux. I understand that inotify will only watch existing files. Do I understand correctly?

Is there an alternative to inotify (or similar package) that would allow me to monitor file creation by file type?

EDIT:
what I need is to monitor file creation by mask. I need to monitor a path for *.json, while disregarding other file types.

Comment: `inotify` is great and of course there are libraries on top of it to make it easier to use.

Comment: Inotify will indeed only monitor existing files, as it's kind of impossible to monitor something which doesn't exist. However, you forget that you can monitor *directories* as well.

Comment: Regarding "file types", there's not really different "types" of files in Linux (or generally in the POSIX/UNIX world). But if you monitor the directory for new files, you can check the file extensions to see if it's what you want.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg and in fact file creation is possible to monitor on directories, it also gives you the created file name, I have a small program that does exactly that, I wrote it one to help me with a bug in another software.

Comment: I think the union of your comments so far answers the question very well.  Did you consider making them an answer?  I would surely upvote for it.  It's a bit difficult for someone else to write an answer now as it would smell a bit like plagiarism.

Comment: And you can try using `libmagic` too for the file types. @5gon12eder if none of the commenters has wrote an answer yet you can do it, I think it's ok but of course it's my opinion.

Comment: What I need is to monitor, say, json files (/home/user/path_a/*.json) and disregard all other file types in that path.

Comment: @iharob Thanks.  With your “permission”, I decided to give it a shot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a good use case of *inotify*.  The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) has a pretty good example that is easily transferred to your problem.

Here is a little program that can be used like

```
$ myprog /tmp '*.o' '*.a'
```

to watch the directory `/tmp` for the creation of `*.o` and `*.a` files.  Note that the patterns are quoted to prevent expansion by the shell.  The program runs forever until interrupted by `SIGINT` (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>).

I am using `fnmatch` to match the names of the created files against the patterns and install a signal handler for `SIGINT` that sets a global flag.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fnmatch.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

I define a small preprocessor macro to align the buffer using GCC's `__attribute__` extension.  More on this later when we actually use this macro.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#  define ALIGNAS(TYPE) __attribute__ ((aligned(__alignof__(TYPE))))
#else
#  define ALIGNAS(TYPE) /* empty */
#endif
```

This is a global flag that we'll set in the signal handler to indicate that the program should quit gracefully.

```
static volatile int interrupted = 0;
```

And this is the signal handler itself.

```
static void
interruption_handler(const int s)
{
  if (s == SIGINT)
    interrupted = 1;
}
```

This function is the working-horse of the program.

```
static int
monitor_directory(const char *const directory,
                  const char *const *const patterns,
                  const size_t pattern_count)
{
  int notifyfd = -1;
  int watchfd = -1;
  int ret = 0;
  const char * errmsg = "unknown error";
```

First, we initialize *inotify*.  `inotify_init` will return a file descriptor that we can `read()`  notifications from.  I use blocking I/O so the `read()` will block until an event occurs.

```
  notifyfd = inotify_init();
  if (notifyfd < 0)
    {
      errmsg = "inotify_init";
      goto catch;
    }
```

Now we register files to watch.  In our case, we want to watch a single directory (`directory`) for the creation of new files (`IN_CREATE`).  The returned file descriptor could be used to tell (if an event occurs) to what watched file it belongs.  But since we are watching only a single file (that happens to be a directory) anyway, we don't really need this info.

```
  watchfd = inotify_add_watch(notifyfd, directory, IN_CREATE);
  if (watchfd < 0)
    {
      errmsg = "inotify_add_watch";
      goto catch;
    }
```

Now everything is set up properly and we can start `read()`ing from the notification file descriptor.

```
  while (1)
    {
```

It is not known in advance how much a call to `read` from the *inotify* descriptor will read so we have to read into a `char` buffer.  We wish to align it properly, tough.  See the man page for more comments on this.

```
      char buffer[sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1] ALIGNAS(struct inotify_event);
      const struct inotify_event * event_ptr;
```

`read()` from the file descriptor.  If we get interrupted, the `read()` will unblock and return –1 as it will if an error occurs.

```
      ssize_t count = read(notifyfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
      if (count < 0)
        {
          if (interrupted)
            goto finally;
          errmsg = "read";
          goto catch;
        }
```

We have a new event, handle it.

```
      event_ptr = (const struct inotify_event *) buffer;
      assert(event_ptr->wd == watchfd);
      assert(event_ptr->mask & IN_CREATE);
      if (event_ptr->len)
        {
          size_t i;
```

Try matching the file name against each of our patterns.

```
          for (i = 0; i < pattern_count; ++i)
            {
              switch (fnmatch(patterns[i], event_ptr->name, FNM_PATHNAME))
                {
                case 0:
                  /* Your application logic here... */
                  if (printf("%s\n", event_ptr->name) < 0)
                    {
                      errmsg = "printf";
                      goto catch;
                    }
                  break;
                case FNM_NOMATCH:
                  break;
                default:
                  errmsg = "fnmatch";
                  goto catch;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

finally, we have to do some cleanup.  `close()`ing the file descriptors created by *inotify* will cause it to release any associated resources.

```
 finally:
  if (watchfd >= 0)
    {
      int status = close(watchfd);
      watchfd = -1;
      if (status < 0)
        {
          errmsg = "close(watchfd)";
          goto catch;
        }
    }
  if (notifyfd >= 0)
    {
      int status = close(notifyfd);
      notifyfd = -1;
      if (status < 0)
        {
          errmsg = "close(notifyfd)";
          goto catch;
        }
    }
  return ret;
 catch:
  if (errmsg && errno)
    perror(errmsg);
  ret = -1;
  goto finally;
}
```

And this is how we hook everything together and run the program.

```
int
main(const int argc, const char *const *const argv)
{
  if (argc < 3)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s DIRECTORY PATTERN...\n", argv[0]);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  {
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = interruption_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
  }
  if (monitor_directory(argv[1], argv + 2, argc - 2) < 0)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: That's a handy piece of sample code except for the `C++` tag - that `catch` is a keyword.

Comment: @Petesh I decided to write a C example program to be more general. (The question is tagged `c` and `c++`.)  I'm used to using `catch` as a label in C to make it clear that I'm using `goto` to mimic exception handling.  Yes, this means the code won't compile as C++ code but I consider this more a feature than a bug because it reminds us not to use `goto` error handling in C++.  However, if you need dual language support, renaming the label would be a minor edit.

Comment: @5gon12eder why do you need the *struct sigaction* block on the main? things seem to wrok without it.

Comment: @mousomer It is used to ensure an orderly shutdown when SIGINT is received. In a real program, you'd use whatever main loop suits your application. If you don't install a handler, SIGINT by default will terminate your application without cleanup.